# eliminate white space from input field

Tags: javascript, html

i am having difficulty trying to get rid of white space (created by pressing the space bar) while user enters email in email field,How can i do this....see my code below..i want to get rid off the blank spaces after the email is entered by space bar or how can i get rid of these spaces as soon as i click submit button !, thanks in advance...singhy

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function removeSpaces(string) {
 return string.split(' ').join('');
}
</script>
<script>
function IsEmpty(){
  if(document.forms['frm'].email.value == "")
  {
    alert("email address here");
    return false;
  }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

```html
<form name="frm" class="rform" method="post" action="form_acknowledge.php" >
<fieldset><legend><strong>test</strong></legend> 
<p>enter email address</p>
  
<p><label for="email">Email address:</label> <input title="Your email address." required name="email" type='email' pattern=".+(@gmail.com)|.+(@hotmail.co.uk)" required />
</p>

<input id="insert" onclick="return IsEmpty();" style="float: right;" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the `blur` event. You are attaching it to the button, and blur means when an element loses the focus, so must to be in the input text not in the button. See the example:

```js
function removeSpaces(string) {
 return string.split(' ').join('');
}
function IsEmpty(){
  if(document.forms['frm'].email.value == "")
  {
    alert("email address here");
    return false;
  }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="frm" class="rform" method="post" action="form_acknowledge.php" >
<fieldset><legend><strong>test</strong></legend> 
<p>enter email address</p>
  
<p><label for="email">Email address:</label> <input title="Your email address." required name="email" type='email' pattern=".+(@gmail.com)|.+(@hotmail.co.uk)" required onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);"/>
</p>

<input id="insert" onclick="return IsEmpty();" style="float: right;"  type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</fieldset>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "block" space when user use input: 
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darxide/oz73u4eg/

```
<input type="text" id="mail" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('mail').addEventListener('keydown' ,function(e) {
    var k =e.keyCode
    k ==32 &&e.preventDefault()
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `trim()` javascript method it removes all the whitespaces between start and end string